# Why is $\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis

**Rudin Theorem** $7.16$

> Let $\alpha$ be monotonicaly increasing on $[a,b]$.Suppose $f_n\in  \mathcal{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a,b]$ for $n=1,2,3,....$ and suppose  $f_n \to f$   uniformly on $[a,b]$.Then  $f\in \mathcal{R}[a,b]$ and  $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_a^b f_n \, \mathrm{d}\alpha = \int_a^b f \, \mathrm{d}\alpha$.

In the last paragraph Rudin says that $$0 \le \int^{-} f \, \mathrm{d}\alpha - \int_{-}f \, \mathrm{d}\alpha \le 2 \epsilon_n[\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)]=0.$$

My confusion is that why $\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)=0$ ?

Comment: Did you really mean $f_n\in  \mathcal{R}(\alpha)?$ If so, maybe later also mean $f\in  \mathcal{R}(\alpha)?$

Comment: Yes, in the book  $f_n\in  \mathcal{R}(\alpha)$  is given @ThomasAndrews

Comment: Is that exactly what Rudin said? He probably meant if $0\leq x\leq \epsilon y$ for all $\epsilon>0$ then $x=0.$

Comment: oks  @ThomasAndrews but here if we put $y=0$  then$ x=0$

Comment: But it is true when $y>0,$ too. We only know that $0\leq x\leq \epsilon y$ for all $\epsilon>0.$ But if $x>0$ then there is, by the Archimedean property of the real numbers, some integer $n$ so that $nx>y$ so for $\epsilon=\frac{1}{n}$ we'd have $x>\epsilon y.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Rudin really wrote:

> $$0\leq\text{left side }\leq 2\epsilon_n(\alpha(b)-\alpha(a))=0\tag{1}$$

then it would be wrong. However, if he wrote:

> $$0\leq\text{left side}\leq 2\epsilon_n(\alpha(b)-\alpha(a))\tag2$$ implies $$\text{left side} = 0$$

it would be correct, assuming something like $\epsilon_n\to 0.$

If he wrote (1), he almost certainly meant (2).

Given any real $x,y\geq 0,$ if it is true that, for all $\epsilon>0,$  $x\leq \epsilon y,$ then $x=0.$

This is true whether $y=0$ or $y>0.$

This follows by the Archimedean Property of the real numbers. If $x>0,$ then there is an integer $n>0$ such that $nx>y.$ But then, for $\epsilon=\frac1n>0$ we'd have $x>\epsilon y,$ contradicting our assumption. So $x=0.$